# installing problem with MMCV (error: subprocess-exited-with-error)

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, transformer-model, openmmlab

I was trying to do some experiment with Pretrained model ViTPose: Simple Vision Transformer Baselines for Human Pose Estimation on google colab. however, i keep getting error from install mmcv. can you save me here?

```
!git clone https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmcv.git
%cd /content/mmcv
!git status
!git init
!git checkout v1.3.9
!MMCV_WITH_OPS=1 pip install -e .
```

```
Obtaining file:///content/mmcv
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting addict (from mmcv-full==1.3.9)
  Downloading addict-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.8 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from mmcv-full==1.3.9) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from mmcv-full==1.3.9) (9.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from mmcv-full==1.3.9) (6.0.1)
Collecting yapf (from mmcv-full==1.3.9)
  Downloading yapf-0.40.2-py3-none-any.whl (254 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 254.7/254.7 kB 3.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=6.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from yapf->mmcv-full==1.3.9) (6.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs>=3.5.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from yapf->mmcv-full==1.3.9) (3.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tomli>=2.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from yapf->mmcv-full==1.3.9) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from importlib-metadata>=6.6.0->yapf->mmcv-full==1.3.9) (3.16.2)
Installing collected packages: addict, yapf, mmcv-full
  Running setup.py develop for mmcv-full
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
    × python setup.py develop did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> See above for output.
    
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py develop did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was that I changed to using another version:

```
pip3 install mmcv==1.5.0
pip3 install mmcv-full==1.5.0
```